# Choose between django.shortcuts.render and django.views.generic.TemplateView

Tags: python, django

I have gone through several Django tutorial.

I notice to generate dynamic web content, based on a static HTML template file, there are 2 ways

- Use `django.conf.urls.url` in `url.py`. Point to a named function which will call `django.shortcuts.render`.
- Use `django.urls.path` in `url.py`. Point to a named class which inherits from `django.views.generic.TemplateView`.

Both ways produce same outcome.

I was wondering, how can we decide which ways to use for a given situation?

Comment: The function based views are the older version - however, still very usefull. Class Based Views were introduced in later django versions. My personal recommendation would be - if you are new to django - stick to the CBVs as they are more powerfull (I have to admit that I keep using both variants).

Comment: The `TemplateView` (which is basically a `View` with `TemplateMixin`) does some extra magic: it for example has separate functions where one can change the context, engine, etc.: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L108 It thus more "separates" logic into atomic subelements. Usually class-based views can be useful if you want for example to *subclass* behavior. Furthermore it is more declarative style.

Comment: Why do you say there more powerful? Is there things you can do with cbv's you can't do with function based?

Comment: @Asher: no, of course not, since that would invalidate the Turing completeness of Python. It is more that things are structured to *easily* change things.

Comment: It is indeed the magic behind Class Based Views - when you understand it, you will love it.

Comment: The only thing I can add to this is that class based views get criticised for being less readable than function based views. This is very subjective though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both *class-based views (CBVs)* and *function-based views (FBVs)* can do the same things: one can always "convert" a CBV to an FBV and vice-versa in the sense that that specific view is functionally equivalent.

## In favor of *class-based views (CBVs)*

CBV are typically used to *abstract away* common logic. For example in a template view, you never need to call the `render(..)`, this is done implicitly for us: we only need to provide the name of the template. Furthermore if later it turns out there is a problem with a certain "code flow", this can easily be patched in the specific view, and thus all views are fixed at once, whereas if the error is located in FBVs, then we need to patch *all* these FBVs.

It also splits up a view in a set of *reusable* components: for example a `DetailView` has a component where it calculates the object to render, a component where one can add extra data to the context, and a method that performs the actual rendering. If you later want to allow to make a POST request on that view, you already have those components available.

CBVs also easily allow to create *ad-hoc* control flows, by using *object-oriented* techniques like *(multiple) inheritance* and *mixins*: instead of implementing a specific control flow, one can define a mixin, and then mix it into the views that should have an altered control flow.

It also makes it easy to *subclass* a view: if you have a view that shows *all* records, than it takes a two-liner, to subclass that view to paginate the records in a new view. If later you change the old record view, then this change also immediately has impact on all the subclasses (this can however sometimes have *undesirable side-effects*).

The handling of different HTTP requests is also *cleaner* in the sense that these are separate methods (a view can have a `get(..)`, `post(..)`, `patch(..)`, etc. method) whereas in a function-based view, this will typically be handled with an `if request.method == 'POST'`. Usually this results in the fact that non-POST requests (for example a PATCH) is handled as if it is a GET, whereas it might be advisable then to return a "405 Method Not Allowed" error. This can be perfectly handled by a function-based view, but it requires some extra work, and therefore is frequently left out.

Finally Django has many generic `View` subclasses that handle common cases like rendering a list of objects, creating or updating a new instance of a model object, etc. Many use cases are (almost) perfectly covered by a CBV, and thus only require to subclass that specific view, and then fill in the details (the name of the template, a reference to the model, etc.). This results also in more *declarative* programming: say *what* you want, not *how* you want it. For example Django's `ListView` has support for pagination.

## In favor of *function-based views* (FBVs)

A function-based view however *shows* the control flow, whereas in a class-based view, this is hidden, and is thus more *Django magic*. Not being able to see the control flow can make it harder to *debug* the view, since all kinds of operations are done "behind the curtains", and it is possible that due to some peculiarity of a certain view, an error occurs.

Function-based views also tend to be easier to implement: you get a `request` object and optionally some (URL) parameters, and you need to turn that into a HTTP Response. You do not have to reason about *what object do I need to fetch*: you can simply fetch objects in an ad-hoc style in the function (well you also *can*, do that in a CBV, but this is not really the idea behind a CBV).

Finally Django also offers a large collection of function decorators like `@login_required` (there are counter-parts for CBVs). It is typically easier to reason about the implications of a function decorator, than about the implications of *subclassing* a view: subclassing can have impact on *all* the methods of a view. Furthermore subclassing with multiple inheritance is not always straightforward: Python uses the *Method Resolution Order (MRO)* to decide what the `super().some_method()` is, but this can result in some tricky side-effects that might not have been foreseen by the implementors of the `View`s or view mixins.

## Django's shift towards class-based views

When you look at the development of Django however, you see a shift from function-based views, to class-based views: for example in [django-2.1](/questions/tagged/django-2.1), the `login` function-based view has been removed. The CBV counterpart (`LoginView`) was introduced in [django-1.11](/questions/tagged/django-1.11). This however does not mean Django developers have to write everything as a CBV: Django typically covers rather generic views, and so using CBVs makes more sense in that case.

Comment: One thing regarding class-based is that, it isn't clear on what member variables we need to override, without going through tone of documentations and tutorials (Example, `LoginRequiredMixin` allows us to override member variable named `login_url` and `redirect_field_name`). For function-based, the things are more obvious, as they are part of function parameter names. May I know, how can we tackle such shortcomings in class-based?

Comment: An IDE can show the attributes the mixin introduces that thus can be overriden (IDEs like PyCharm also have a Django plugin making this a bit easier), but except for that reading the documentation is typically the only thing you can do. For example: https://django-braces.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/access.html